# How to check the authorization status using android-evernote sdk?

Tags: android, ios, evernote

Im developing an android application which uses **evernote android sdk** for some evernote process.

The login is successfull and authorization is also working.

How can I check if the authorization status is valid or invalid after the login.

Based on following method

```
com.evernote.client.android.EvernoteSession.isLoggedIn()
```

It only returns the login status.It returns true if login was succesfull otherwise it returns false.

In **ios-evenote sdk** they have the variable 

in the class -**ENSession.h** 

 with the help of property **isAuthenticated** we can find the the authorization status.

Like that i want to know the authorization status.For instance I was logged in today and gave authorization for 1 day and did not logout.After that I closed my app without using the logout session.

Tomorrow I want to check the status of authorization. How can I do that? **Is there is any method available in the evernote android sdk?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps to get the session status whether it is active or not

1. check the login status
2. if login success means then call any api method that is listing the notebooks,etc
3. If it is success means session is valid otherwise invalid session

For instance sample code is given below

```
final SessionCheckingCallback callback_final = callback;
if (!mEvernoteSession.isLoggedIn()) {
    Log.d(SESSION_CHECK_TAG, "Session expired.Session not logged in");
    callback.onSessionExpired();
}

try {
    AsyncNoteStoreClient asyncNoteStoreClient = mEvernoteSession.getClientFactory().createNoteStoreClient();
    asyncNoteStoreClient.listNotebooks
            (
                    new OnClientCallback<List<Notebook>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(List<Notebook> data) {
                            //Session valid

                            callback_final.onSessionSuccess();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onException(Exception exception)
                        {
                            exception.printStackTrace();

                            if (exception instanceof EDAMUserException)
                            {
                                Log.d(SESSION_CHECK_TAG, "exception is EDAMUserException");
                                EDAMUserException eDAMUserException = (EDAMUserException) exception;

                                if (eDAMUserException.getErrorCode() == EDAMErrorCode.AUTH_EXPIRED) {
                                    Log.d(SESSION_CHECK_TAG, "Session expired");
                                    callback_final.onSessionExpired();
                                } else {
                                    Log.d(SESSION_CHECK_TAG, "Session not expired");
                                    callback_final.onSessionSuccess();
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Log.d(SESSION_CHECK_TAG, "exception is not EDAMUserException");
                                Log.d(SESSION_CHECK_TAG, "Session expired");
                                callback_final.onSessionExpired();
                            }


                        }
                    }
            );

} catch (Exception ex) {

    ex.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("Session check", "session expired due to exception ");
    callback.onSessionExpired();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: 
     `EvernoteSession.getInstance().isLoggedIn()`

to get the current authentication status of the user.  Just make sure you are using the most up to date (v2+) version of the SDK (available here: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-android)

Multiple examples in the readme for the SDK utilize this method for the purpose you describe including this one: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-android/blob/master/README.md#creating-a-note-asynchronously